# Error 500 on Get even though JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet is set

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an MVC application that is utilising SignalR

The controller has...

```vb
'GET: Home/DiaryEntries
Function DiaryEntries(<DataSourceRequest> request As DataSourceRequest) As ActionResult
    'get a list of all Headline diary entries
    'removed for brevity... HLDiary list is an IQueryable(Of DiaryEntry)
    'DiaryEntry is an object with 7 properies

    Return Json(HLDiaryList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

End Function
```

My Home/Index view has the following javascript

```
    function outputHLDiaryEntries() {

        $.getJSON("Home/DiaryEntries", function (json) {

            var out = "";
            var i;

            for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

                out += '<div class="dOuter"><div class="dRow1">';
                out += '<div class="dDate">' + json.results[i].dDate + '</div>';
                out += '<div class="dRef">' + json.results[i].dRef + '</div>';
                out += '<div class="dTeam">' + json.results[i].dTeam + '</div>';
                out += '<div class="dTeam">' + json.results[i].dCreatedBy + '</div>';
                out += '<div class="' + json.results[i].dType + '">' + json.results[i].dType + '</div></div>';
                out += '<div class="dServers">' + json.results[i].dServers + '</div>';
                out += '<div class="dComment">' + htmlEncode(json.results[i].dComment) + '</div></div>';

            }

            $('#diaryTable').innerHTML = out;

        });
    }
```

Unfortunately when outputHLDiaryEntries() is called it returns a 500 error

- Name= http://localhost/UIS/Home/DiaryEntries
- Protocol=HTTP
- Method=GET
- Result=500
- Content type=text/html
- Received=7.36 KB
- Time=238.03 ms
- Initiator=XMLHttpRequest

and the error is

> This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

As you can see I've allowed Get Behaviour in my function...

```
Return Json(HLDiaryList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

Why is this and how can I fix... I'm out of ideas

Comment: Have you tried adding a breakpoint to be sure you're executing the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

this issue occurred due to CORS (cross origin request).

I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452925/what-sensitive-information-could-be-disclosed-when-setting-jsonrequestbehavior?rq=1) will help you !!