# Can we use Post method to fetch data from DB or only GET is used?

Tags: java, rest, http

Please let me know when to use GET method and when POST in REST API. As Post is supposed to be more secure, so can we use in case of getting the data from the database in REST API or it just can be used in case of adding new record in the database. Thanks for your views.

Comment: One is not more secure than the other.

Comment: The only thing more secure about POST is that the request payload is usually not logged by the server.

Comment: In brief

Use GET for safe and idempotent requests
Use POST for neither safe nor idempotent requests

Comment: also a lot of XSRF prevention is done for POST/PUT only assuming the GET operation is not updating any data. How secure the API is, is down to how the developer secures it not that POST is inherently more secure than GET unless there is something I've missed

Answer (score 5):

Usecases for each method:

- `GET`: "Hi, Mr. Server. Could you please **recover** some information for me?"
- `POST`: "Hi, Mr. Server. Could you please **store** this information for me?"
- `PUT`: "Hi, Mr. Server. Could please **update** the previous info you stored for me?
- `DELETE`: "Hi, Mr. Server. I think I don't need anymore this
  information. Could you please **delete** it for me?

There are some other methods but those are the most common ones

Comment: Unless the query is **very** complex you should use a `GET`. By a "complex query" I mean really complex querys that need, for example, a JSON with nested elements describing them. For regular queries query parameters whould be enough

Answer (score 0):

The following thread has a nice answer regarding this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37331668/8558426

TL;DR:
 **Which method should you use?**

It depends on the operation you are performing. In REST APIs, the POST method is frequently used to create resources while the GET method is frequently used to request a representation of a resource.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I have one Question: For retrieving data should I use GET or POST? which will be better?

Comment: I would always use `GET` for retrieving data.