# how to send the confidential info like username and password in get request for login

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm building a small web application using node.js and react.js which require user login.
How to send the confidential information like username and password in get request?

Comment: Have you checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328684/should-i-use-get-or-post-when-requesting-sensitive-data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely need to use GET you can add the info in the query string:

```
get('https://example.com/login?username=XXX&password=XXX');
```

But this is highly discouraged. Even though the query string is encrypted when using https, this is bad design to use to transport highly sensitive such as password. Some reasons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323200/is-an-https-query-string-secure/323286).

A better way would be to use a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

you don't send data in get request, use post method to send data.